# groupby and average datetime64

Tags: python, pandas

how can i have the average date on a groupby

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame ({'ID' : ['foo', 'bar'] * 5,
               'VAL' : pd.date_range(start='4/1/2012', periods=10)})


ID  VAL
    foo 2012-04-01 00:00:00
    bar 2012-04-02 00:00:00
    bar 2012-04-04 00:00:00
    foo 2012-04-05 00:00:00
    bar 2012-04-06 00:00:00
    foo 2012-04-07 00:00:00
    bar 2012-04-08 00:00:00
    foo 2012-04-09 00:00:00
    bar 2012-04-10 00:00:00
```

desired ouptut :

```
bar 06/04/2012
foo 05/04/2012
```

how can i do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by average date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an alternative (is to view the datetime values as int64, which is how they're stored, and back):

```
In [11]: df['VAL'].astype('int64').groupby(df['ID']).mean().astype('datetime64[ns]')
Out[11]:
ID
bar   2012-04-06
foo   2012-04-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

*Since we're using views here, this should be more efficient/faster than the apply...*

As Jeff points out: this is fixed in master (and so 0.14.1):

```
df.groupby('ID').mean()
```

should "just work".

Answer (score 3):

This takes the mean of the timedeltas then adds back the starting date (this should be working more directly in 0.14.1/master (coming soon), when you can take the mean of a timedelta64)

```
In [10]: m = df['VAL'].min()

In [11]: df.groupby('ID')['VAL'].apply(lambda x: (x-m).mean())+m
Out[11]: 
ID    
bar  0   2012-04-06
foo  0   2012-04-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: i try the mean of a timedelta64 in 0.14.1 ut it doesnt work. is it implemented ?

Comment: not yet https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6884 (but you can do it in the apply; this is for using an aggregate function).

Answer (score 0):

There may be more efficient ways, but one approach would be to convert to an ordinal, take the mean, and convert back to a datetime.

```
In [264]: df['VAL_ordinal'] = df['VAL'].apply(lambda x: x.toordinal())

In [267]: df.groupby('ID')['VAL_ordinal'].mean().apply(lambda x: datetime.fromordinal(int(x)))
Out[267]: 
ID
bar   2012-04-06
foo   2012-04-05
Name: VAL_ordinal, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```